# What does this regular expression mean: /[\[\.]/

Tags: javascript, regex

What does this regular expression mean?

```
var re = /[\[\.]/;
```

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Actually, neither of two slashes is required. `/[[.]/` would work just as fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Javascript`? It means to match any of two characters, `[` or `.`

Answer (score 0):

You shuold first read by your own.Google it and also Check this one.
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions]